# TL072 weird output when used as buffer

Tags: operational-amplifier, waveform

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Dear all, I tried to use TL072CP op amp as a buffer, however to my surprise it outputs a perfect triangular wave with reduced amplitude when given sine wave input of 150kHz and I have used a 12V and -12V rail, + & - rail supply to my op-amp. I simulated the same chip in LT Spice and it the output should be the same as input waveform with low impedance. This is very weird and I hope someone can point out to me why it does not output a sine wave same as the input waveform.

All circuits are connected properly and if you can see there is a small strip of short wire connecting pin 1 to 2

Thank you for reading and have a nice day !!

Comment: what is the slew rate limit of your opamp, and what is the peak slew rate of your signal?

Comment: Page 17 of the [TL07xx datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl074.pdf?ts=1664650158036&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) (down at the bottom).

Comment: When you say the op-amp is properly connected, what do you mean by that? Where is it connected and how? There seems to be no bypass caps on power supply pins. And it can't drive an arbitrary capacitive load directly, such as a coaxial cable.

Comment: @Justme, hi sir, it is connected as shown in the LT Spice schematic above

Comment: @Transistor, so it the output expected to be traingular, sir :)?

Comment: No, it's not expected, but depending on the environment, it may work poorly. The simulator is an ideal environment. The breadboard and jumper leads flying around is a very poor environment. And so, as it is still unknown what wires etc you used in your real world circuit, as it might explain the poor operation. Your setup may have an issue not visible in your photos.

Comment: "*so it the output expected to be traingular, sir :)?*" If you've hit the maximum slew-rate then you can expect a triangle waveform. "*sir :)?*" There are ladies here too!

Comment: Are you sure V13 is ok? Yes, but when you use a symbol with a "+", let it be the "+" voltage.

Comment: It looks like you connected a positive voltage to both power rails.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing would be adding bypass caps next to the IC.

One problem is breadboards have many parasitics. There's parasitic inductance in the wires that slows down the current from the supply. If the load (tl027) changes and needs more current the jumper wires will restrict that current with their inductance. Also make sure the wires that go back to the supply are "big", the bigger the wire, the lower
Inductance the wire will have. If you have any wires that are 28 gauge or lower that may be a problem.

Another problem with breadboards is the parasitic capacitance between rows, this can amount to a few picofarads between rows and create crosstalk.

Last problem is contact resistance, some bread boards and wires may not make great contacts so make sure the wires and the breadboard are making good contact.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for the advice!! Just wondering, can you show me how to add the bypass caps next to IC , perhaps in a diagram or so :) ?

Comment: They go between vcc and gnd and vcc- and gnd make sure your ground is good

Answer (score 0):

Well, the key point is that your output has 1.19V peak-to-peak, a far cry from the 12.6Vpp on the input.  This just means that your circuit is far too slow to follow the input signal.  It is not a matter of too low supply voltage or the output signal would not have sharp triangular corners but a more clipped look.

Now the TL072 has a specified output slew rate of 13V/µs which is far more than we need for the signal: a 145kHz signal is roughly 1Mradian/sec and with an amplitude of 6.3V, we need to support a slew rate of 6V/µs which is half of what we should be able to do while the output is (squinting) about 0.3V/µs.

Suspect #1 would be your supply lines of ±12V.  As said elsewhere, you need a bypass capacitor across the supply lines that will support surge demands of current without having to go through long connections.

Apropos long connections: you write

> you can see there is a small strip of short wire connecting pin 1 to 2

but frankly, there is no "short wire" anywhere on the photograph: not a single wire is short enough to fit wholly on the photograph.  With comparatively high frequencies, that is also asking for trouble.

Then the output current of the TL072 is 10mA.  That means that to support a slew rate of 6V/µs, the load capacity must not exceed 1.6nF, and that leaves us with no extra current for the ohmic part of the load.

What kind of load capacity/resistance has your probe?  Looks like a 50ohm cable...

The manual of your oscilloscope has some calibration instructions akin to

> Check the shape of the display waveform, and if necessary, adjust the variable capacitance on the probe with a non-metallic screwdriver until the waveform displayed on the screen is “properly compensated” as shown in the figure below.

Did you properly "adjust the variable capacitance"?  Because that could be the elephant in the room...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your insight, I will try it again tonight :). So, you are saying that we should be expecting a sine output too with the same waveform and shape and this TL072 should be able to buffer such high frequency?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility: the TL072 contains two opamps and you leave all pins of the second opamp unconnected.  That may cause it to oscillate or otherwise draw current that the first opamp needs.

Try taking the second opamp out of the equation by grounding its + input and connecting its output to its - input.

And then a blocking capacitor (something like 1uF low ESR) across the supply pins of the TL072 and without long wires might help making the current available it needs for changing its output voltage fast enough against parasitic/load capacitances.